# Zend Framework 2 Remember Me without Custom Code

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I do authentication using Zend Framework 2. The code follows documentation 
[Introduction to Zend\Authentication](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html)

```
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Digest as AuthAdapter;
...
$authService = new AuthenticationService();
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($passwordFile, $realm, $username, $password);
$result = $authService->authenticate($authAdapter);
```

> By default, `Zend\Authentication` provides persistent storage of the identity from a successful authentication attempt using the PHP session.

I want to configure persistent storage to keep data for 1 week (if user checks the 'remember me' check box). I don't want to develop custom storage class.

How the 'remember me' feature might be implemented using existing Zend Framework 2 code?

I think extending session live time is not a perfect solution. We should keep some information about user in a cookie. Is it possible to configure Zend Framework to retrieve information from saved cookie and use it for authentication?

P.S. I do know how to write custom storage class but I want to throw away any additional custom code. The less code we have the less we should support.

Comment: the only way to do this without custom code is to set cookie and session ttl

Comment: I understand this. But I think that extending the session time is not a perfect solution. If I'm going to save something in the cookie I should validate this information when reading the cookie. This might be some token which is saved on the server side etc. The question is - is there any solution for this in Zend Framework. I read the library code and I think no. May be I missed something.

Comment: Why don't you want to extend the session time?

Comment: I don't want to extend session time because of 2 reasons. Both reasons are not really critical. Anyway searching for a better solution would not heart. Find my reasons below. 1). Old session files are cleaned regularly by the server. How do we know that session file should not be deleted? We can examine the file content and leave required session files. But we should change standard logic in a different place for this. 2). In other places in the code we might expect that session is closed when user closes the browser. This is quite ordinary normal behavior. I can explain this if needed.